# error in the output using python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, mime, pcm

input.txt:

```
I am Hungry
I am going home
I am going to Germany
```

complete code:

```
    class Part(object):



    """Represent a part in a multipart messsage"""

    def __init__(self, name, contentType, data, paramName=None):

        super(Part, self).__init__()

        self.name = name

        self.paramName = paramName

        self.contentType = contentType

        self.data = data



    def encode(self):

        body = BytesIO()



        if self.paramName:

            body.write('Content-Disposition: form-data; name="%s"; paramName="%s"\r\n' % (self.name, self.paramName))

        else:

            body.write('Content-Disposition: form-data; name="%s"\r\n' % (self.name,))



        body.write("Content-Type: %s\r\n" % (self.contentType,))

        body.write("\r\n")

        body.write(self.data)



        return body.getvalue()



class Request(object):

    """A handy class for creating a request"""

    def __init__(self):    

        super(Request, self).__init__()

        self.parameters = []



    def add_json_parameter(self, name, paramName, data):

        self.parameters.append(Part(name=name, paramName=paramName, contentType="application/json; charset=utf-8", data=data))



    def add_audio_parameter(self, name, paramName, data):

        self.parameters.append(Part(name=name, paramName=paramName, contentType="audio/x-wav;codec=pcm;bit=16;rate=16000", data=data))



    def encode(self):

        boundary = uuid.uuid4().hex

        body = BytesIO()



        for parameter in self.parameters:

            body.write("--%s\r\n" % (boundary,))

            body.write(parameter.encode())

            body.write("\r\n")



        body.write("--%s--\r\n" % (boundary,))



        return body.getvalue(), boundary



host = "mtldev08.nuance.com"

port = 443

uri = "/NmspServlet/"
Error_Status = 0


RequestData = """{

    "appKey": "9c9fa7201e90d3d96718bc3f36ce4cfe1781f2e82f4e5792996623b3b474fee2c77699eb5354f2136063e1ff19c378f0f6dd984471a38ca5c393801bffb062d6",

    "appId": "NMDPTRIAL_AutomotiveTesting_NCS61HTTP",

    "uId": "Alexander",

    "inCodec": "PCM_16_8K",

    "outCodec": "PCM_16_8K",

    "cmdName": "NVC_TTS_CMD",

    "appName": "Python",

    "appVersion": "1",

    "language": "eng-GB",

    "carrier": "carrier",

    "deviceModel": "deviceModel",

    "cmdDict": {

        "tts_voice": "Serena",

        "tts_language": "eng-GB",

        "locale": "canada",

        "application_name": "Testing Python Script",

        "organization_id": "NUANCE",

        "phone_OS": "4.0",

        "phone_network": "wifi",

        "audio_source": "SpeakerAndMicrophone",

        "location": "47.4925, 19.0513",

        "application_session_id": "1234567890",

        "utterance_number": "5",

        "ui_langugage": "en",

        "phone_submodel": "nmPhone2,1",

        "application_state_id": "45"        

    }

}"""



TEXT_TO_READ = """{

    "tts_type": "text",

    "tts_input": "DUMMY"

}"""

scriptPath = os.path.abspath(__file__)
scriptPath = os.path.dirname(scriptPath)
fileInput = os.path.join(scriptPath, "input.txt")
if not os.path.exists(fileInput):
    print "error message"
    Error_Status = 1
    sys.exit(Error_Status)
try:
    content = open(fileInput, "r")
except IOError:
    print "error message"
    Error_Status = 1
    sys.exit(Error_Status)
for line in content.readlines():
    line = line.strip('\n')
    if len(line):
        TEXT_TO_READ = json.loads(TEXT_TO_READ)
        TEXT_TO_READ["tts_input"]=line
        TEXT_TO_READ = json.dumps(TEXT_TO_READ)
        print json.dumps(TEXT_TO_READ)
        #TEXT_TO_READ = json.loads(TEXT_TO_READ)
        #print TEXT_TO_READ


request = Request()
request.add_json_parameter("RequestData", None, RequestData)
request.add_json_parameter("TtsParameter", "TEXT_TO_READ", TEXT_TO_READ)
body, boundary = request.encode()

h = httplib.HTTPSConnection(host, port)
h.set_debuglevel(0)

headers = {

"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=%s" % (boundary,),

"Connection": "Keep-Alive",

}

h.request('POST', uri, body, headers)
res = h.getresponse()
data = """MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=--Nuance_NMSP_vutc5w1XobDdefsYG3wq
""" + res.read()

msg = email.message_from_string(data)

for index, part in enumerate(msg.walk(), start=1):
    content_type = part.get_content_type()
    payload = part.get_payload()
    print res.getheaders()

    if content_type == "audio/x-wav" and len(payload):
        with open('output.pcm'.format(index), 'wb') as f_pcm:
            print f_pcm.write(payload)
    elif content_type == "application/json":
        with open('json.txt'.format(index), 'w') as f_json:
            print f_json.write(payload)
sys.exit(Error_Status)
```

I want to read the `input.txt` line by line and send that as a request to the server and later save the response respectively. I am sending the request and it is working fine, so I din add the code and later parsing the response and saving the binary as pcm file and rest as .txt file. But my above code is not generating any output.

Response from the server:
just for one example in the input.txt : I am hungry

```
----Nuance_NMSP_vutc5w1XobDdefsYG3wq
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Audio"; paramName="TEXT_TO_READ"
Content-Type: audio/x-wav;codec=pcm;bit=16;rate=8000
Nuance-Context: 101f04eb-2393-45e1-a005-528b11748a7f

                   êÿûÿøÿ M ? w ûÿA àÿúÿ¡ lã _ #c #â Ðÿ‚ÿe «,ÎÿœüàûÜýêÿöÿHÿîüüšóãä øÅ~6ùsååê7û7“‡þÿ½þª
ðÙn‘jBÚ )/Ä#‰
räõÓgîº òVú#êcð!ùûŽóñ;î§ñZìƒäŽß…åð&õhñžíûééëìðŒõNüVýmÿÅq#ï›"Ý)0ª8„>Kš(HËÔ¿^Ù¿+ŸG.ôÓÕ*êuVÞÓïÁîÙý¯ù—óÆâ¥é¿ùx‹ÇþW÷Éû÷»ïØßÆßï»ú×ûð‹çâæ[í˜ôIöƒøtø ÷¢öÈõ¶þR   þ 3"<&N-:6I?•CçAçô§Õºß Ò?Ì.š    ãmé¥ ¨ËúUðKäñïãëãâ‰ëÚñæïvêHé+îÀìûæ©â+è”ô_ûù;ò
ñÂófø#ýAy
%ÈÞÛ%r+¸4‰@)Oî7^ÞÞáå&W-ŠxôBñTùÅÿÛîÒì¼çêì"ësçÔé©ë™ìRé­ènï4ñVîÈåã«èóñÊöÝõŸó=óöŸùxüýÿÜ³ÿüLx%ü(]1è9MÈFK"ÿüŽÑ~ç¤
8º6
€ïåáÖôà ÙþXïäåªâå!äòããûá    éRí­ðíŒæôááçÒï‰÷úì÷ÃôôgùÚþ%N›
3æ,¤8„;LK&D+-#\ä€ì¬
‡(<'t
Ëò ñFøÒœüåð•çòåIéÞè`æÈáúÝéà¾éqílî·ç á*Ü3á²ìÔõbø‹ó—îðøõIUÄ “ù    Òa!U$ó-ú7¤?ýKo8|ø©éX+#/þ8÷×ü_úüÜð/ì£ïríEëâ/ÞÕàøàïè í8î¯êß–ØtÜŒëÂ÷‘øèòí8ïV÷lÿÏ›†±×   mZ;%L)0¸>J1î$('<$Ïßêíû¦C'BÅð’ðSó€ü&ÿšî'ñï¦êêå!ì©ñÚééß(Ü<çîwäjÖÑØ¤ëü7ûñìEæí°ú¼òÈývÿ®î
À
z &#.g2-22B-ø%ùsêÐ¥ÂÿªøVüÐÿ¿ù}ðHì>ò2ó5ï‘çgåQç´æ9ç–èBêAèÊÚšÌÏØÄïWÿù<çã!ï±ÿšôý”úÚÿ[é 8[$6S?ú6]EŸ%(ŸXÿáû`Å–‰Šòcð“ì/øDöí—ëæç’íîæ”ãµæºçzæòÑ%ÈéÜnø||õäá‹ãRôœaû%þ†Ê­_$w,¼8K@9c( ×>Õ!•%é<ÿTàî2ø2òßëi÷ÊøäòTëÔæ^ëòvíLæ†ä¢æ»åÜØËØÍìéóþ¹üðëŒàéœúv¡ÿÁü”¢>|+/e0#9çF"=ë& ò‰êÆ
9/¶9JN÷'óá oƒÆññÎòñó£óàïõë^îÞï‚î7ëîè<éè)ÜRÍ‹Ä:×ü÷ê ñô¸ããÞòUü ü.üÉU¸ .Ö0m9ý2n6;5¼"ÝûÄöŸô$_"¼¥ÿVÙ ]ü¯ûfñœö?òtò9ôìPì)ï²ïÁí>êDènê!çxâ/Óu¿õÊ_ï0
ìçYÝ+êùü“üqæG5Ì6õ=8Ç8P?Ì?ŸWá»ó—´6x+v¦ýrÿø ýõ‚óÊüoð_ðÑíï‚ôpðïçënë¤êdè©ãà\ÑÅ~ÐÉð$Cüqé¨äùí°ô%õöüàó\Œk 1“4¤2';ûDðDû ÞiëÔÅ9–*¨êúv£üôÌò÷Í®óæïSòsôHò½åì#íÏæýåªèpß†Ì}¼Ö5ûË ¸ñýåAíV÷Qñðjþ!$4'5-ù+9ÍMò>úïÙ­øu&ö*†P
C
Pù^êeøÖü°ú×î-ðò)ð í˜î]ñ›ó{ëÏç–èwìšç—ÙÊÌpÎžì·ûâøuóŸî"î—ê†ê^ûé
×¦Ñ"Î#7,Ä62ñ?I*3·€Ü’#l(–c
Š   n)ëaç$ü2ûTù—ëâò4÷yñçïuïÀïŸè‘ç3îfð0ß¾Ð¦ÊØßófõöuô{ïêèXõO#ä‹7"‹1¨6b5Ä?‡FÒ6þÛá#.
Sª
¾   ¨êêàøTÿ3öè÷ìåõöóYí$ì-ïð4æ
åÏï5óxâ>ÖU×lÛfâFñ;ûxüuô éÁêÞò|ö/ÿ_øR@Ý2‚0Ð,û8«GDG3ÛtòÇ%¨"?mîuç“÷Õ÷‰õ²òØôýöÝîðêêìÎñËïåê¾ðXð8äÚ=Ñ#ØœèOõûö‚õò?ì¶ézïáøe#‡
}ø™X&P3ï8Ž4>?ŸD]¯ö¬ògøË‚[ôAå_íBöŒôèïÏóRúÄö8ìéçËêxñÀð~ëbñýô8ñfìÞÛ•Ì‰Ò¨æøú1 ¬û'õ˜éãé«ôÉÿƒ¥
<¦Öôj6„Cý,:3ÔI?`«áÉú`9
µ³ 
EïÜg÷ïúªæåéæûùÿûñºæÒì¡òë²çò÷ùÌôìËãË× Ð°Ûbõ 4û7õþïséçä@íÀý)C
N
Ùù#~5L/ê+ˆJwL!yï î“
Ê&ø[òoß½ñšö‹éÚëþfòòå¸î{õ±í\ê¨ôÙ÷¶óí3ð<õ£â ÄÑÑKøýüûú#õøæ Ú+äûÿø%‹
'`4ê5Á)…7ÅN >¥¬Þ¤ùÙØlà b‹Þ½à®ò¦ðòèôú
'ü;íŒèKì¹ð9íTñ¸÷uùõËïHë]ÞFÒPÝ÷ý¨úóøÌð{åÐßõé,þy  
Tu`*1ª$N+IjL_(¹øbé4G
C,òÒñÜFê…òÌçIì_|ùóåå`ìyõúðféüõ
ÿŒø¬ïAðÍówèÔÓ6×åìüý
ù õÅë²Þhâªõ²’Œ]#‡Ï$ 0@0±2ˆ@6Pd/æû§èÊô¬
/\ R¨ð}à    è—ï‚ð»ó‚ö0 oöèCìõ¸òtï8ñ¼ø ù–ñ[ð¢óîô×4Óì»üéø-ù2÷eì\ááâ±ôåuï²†±/( §/I*=-1;Iy>–åêÍæ›a÷!B?ñ™à•ãßô–ñ>ôõý,ü6ð³ì'í+ó×ôQñ¬òÊõtõlð ôù=ï>Ø'ÞÁð"ö˜õ©÷±öð
æç€÷ôÊ¯SH§(„*o.:ñ@‡?Å&çî“ä6üÜã&Uõºç¥æŸñxõ#ó÷ÂønñàêïôóßòŒñö¯öó°ïçð»ô’õ‘å„ÝKñ ýxôòFöóÜëyé¡òA ôüVDÅ
seÀ(Ç-Ò)Ø0;=Hj$½ö™ì?ütfú¸`ãôÉîënï
ðºñÓôUøYð£ë*ïnò¼ðÜñ©ôiôóóïýî«ñ/ô}ôÂð×í)ðîóóuó¦ó`óíó×ö‚ùÚýïW‰#<*{3S7é69¶ úúñGþâ2!î¤¢÷¢ø¤õÆê)íZðúó/÷þïÁé°íÓîSñÛð‹ñïð¼ïŒïƒð,ïÑòØô¢òüðéðþòñõR÷<ö´ó=óõ÷@ü½ >wò   d@%û*Â*3P7ÄB³'òÿüñÒûÉ' à( 3ùøóë‡ëyíÝñçò¼òoëwí¦ê¹ìîƒî˜ï$ñ¹îÕîoî•ñ¡õ¡ö®ô)ð:ðé÷„û.ùÜó0ñ°ó ÷Âúåü+ ¶„h !_(E-…2h98G)öäõÑ
-aÚ—ø)÷–îí“ë-ìtñômð‚í*é«êwíÿï5ñŸðÚî(ïœï¥ñ*óRññâôêø”úø§ôô‹õ„÷ùzüåÿâ@i    ”V!6(6+M/ø5à<1%{àÿ!ýµ8%ãÍ&ü ùØô³óî¥êaê<îïþï¢îŠí}î¯ïžðzññüð³ñ;ôZö:ö6ö.øyú-üÞúó÷1ö\öøëùAû#ü°ý‚ÿ6ûJ    ý˜Ž d&»-%*q!‰á¶ÌÕPñ™þ³ûAú±÷¢ô¼ñ·ð÷ï÷îüíì]ìZíóîŽðNñ2ñ9ñ±ñ€òäóõúõßö÷\örõÆôõ+öw÷ÙøúÌû+þÚ “ôÉ
iFF–"&Œ%ã"O!!' ¦fÜZ
®Ëƒý¯ùõÙñÔîðì¼ë°ê¶èvçÍæµç2é0ê³ê¾ê2ëÀììî¯ðòóQô£õ¼öà÷=ù»úqü?þ çáËÛ¢
ÈdK:"×#®""v"8"F!mâ”
lwÿ
ûöûñ”î§ìì9ëgé®çæ…æîç=é‹étéˆé¶êäìÙîHðƒñÈòôöSøöùhû×ü“þu Kìj*› x˜»¤æž!S#Ä"A"¡"p"!\¥¨ÿ½ú¿õ]ñýíÏë«êpé°çvæ¬å¥å³æ×çÿçñç¢èðéÆëíïðò{ôªöçøôú÷üÿù ¾dv

–bMƒKÁ w#{#§"¥"#"PÕBy/| ”ûlöñ í_êÎè¤ç…æå¢äå÷åèæ‘çéçÁèMê5ì8î
ðzñçòÃô÷”ùùû*þU ,æ¸èp

†Çõ¢j#7$#"q#Ú"A!…i5¶üÈ÷Mò1í–éŸçæ«ä3ããHã`ä|åhæÅæµçÞè±êSí«ïêðïñ{óÄõ~øýú-ýÿ·g.]Ê   `Ö
_‹'×"¿&'Ø%Í$è$$£"¶‡ üúiõ®ï˜ê:çå4ãúáZáßààJá–âÄã7ä~äqæ²é$ìcí¢î‰ðLóVö%ùüJÿÔ¦p‘×    
*¹cG”»!&ª'‘&j$º#î#–"IleýîööïÙêUæ¦ãâÄá à;ß;ÞÞƒßÌá>ãSä,å¸æé$ëõërïÂòVõ¡ùôþŠüÿ
B‚ º¿Ëû $>(S.-1 *¡ Í³O
ç,uÿ-øQófñýîòì†ê‹çGååœãÀàšÞøÜÜÏÞLã çêáì[ívîñ3ô´÷jûwÿ­#sÿ
n}=[É­äâÒ"é%ù%v'œ&%%I2ŒýóÆõœò¾ðXézåtà§â„âßúÞá`ãjãÈãåÇævè4êí•ð)õÄùKü=ýˆþ%5W¡ ;ÿ­ó½ ËÅ[&m'K#œÞÚS7PÎ ðïéBñ£õµðùîÓçmæ™êèâXÛSßeèúí©ïÍíë*ë:ïwô«ø{úºû’ü+þåÞ¨Öûø2"¯6Û+~Ç`kõ ,Î-:ü:"$ùÊüýò÷êÅôßô†ô–îÄâ’ëÅñîŸç4ñZó¬þ\øÙê}ëoö–ú¤€üþM¼\
—‰`c¥]¾¸’Á#jú;> ñPNôÃû,âü{óDýŸÒùÙîeþ  ¸ïKø’>õFèyôäïÿN   jïYá±ìúôá9
ÿÐòó{â¬óÔÿÅ ê€»ðëü<’¶W ÷ïZûÙ    ûû6øûòº£Âua‹Eè³ùÖðï)‘Ûûøûîü•ú9â2çtSúðûóÇôcýö Œ
æ~øÓ¼Šñ¿ö;ÐmÖÿRýœþg
þÿ:úµú® ÌW
úžòvü~è¢úEl ÀÔýVÞUö¨ÌŽ
ã§Ú'ñ£F[ñÅñq^
Úø“ø%þ  „Ôû ÷©þx`ñìØ—ÊìòþôæüÙþOXý°ù®ú[û¶þò$ Ð   É Éï1"ø ó^Vÿ@÷å ]÷˜ð þáý×
×™üÞ©ü{ÿž÷Êùžå ƒÿŒ&ÝÎùÏuü Lü»øˆ4
    ôtò“þ;  åÿèøE^ýRú× UÒýõøúbüœ 1÷5“9–üî÷•÷=ýç T%^ûõøüçžûÿsðò÷FühþÇOþ!²ýöú¢ ×ýTýÂüÈ°ÿ(
)ø ùÒþ
&û­ôØÿ
“ºþû‡ÿ&Äþ…n
Ãÿ÷ËòGýº¾ÿ0Kþ‰ýLýÐÿWú„ïµ ?þàý§ÿñêQ,ûIúúrýÐÿçÿ¹þ¾ÄÿÐ ÷   þ´vr£ýÓü›ýˆRðØüúúhþ¬ü^¨¨Âüû'ûŒ|/–
ý¤ûxý13à~üÄþ(üÃ úüþóþ- ðÿ²øný~¤›þ¯ÿäÿbÿ%2Ë Žÿÿ“ÿÔÜOþIüFùî×–ÿùÿ^ø ÿùüF üaÿ¦ü düZšüüþføyú³%
^äüWöÄûÿ<c¿~WþÐùg Ã¹‹nÿ5ü%ýCþ¢ê½»ý²ø®üþ‘þµ (5ÿþÝýÞþFþ1ø×ü þ¯oYúô¤ýÛÙ´kýúW Ñ 05Zçs&ƒÀ$@*‡þ¹þÅoÛÿ¤ú÷óò¢ùõöÅõõÐ÷%ôØôÌô2óXòDõ÷:õ ô‹ù–þáÿù”  H.ˆö`›>ú:ëPzsR@Û{<ùçù³òZëpêtëqëçðáuß¶ÞBà!ßIßjàÅâÔå±ç2ë(ðhô(ùýŽý(dH
ø1¹¼!²"µ#M&A*á2€4þ3ë3p0×3æ ó[ç“é’ýêDÙÞÖÃÝ!à&ãºÚ~ÕÓôÑCØÞæ°éèè¬çgêÞðkõÐúþäþZŒß£ #:%$'t+ä*52&4¹?ü8xI+bôÝ$à*&ö!§)ätÖcèÿæÁí@â@×²Ó‡Ñv×äáæâ£ê âàbÝþÝßá˜è‰íüõ„ö üüúðÿ[Kè}¥!€&3v7—;©=ÄBmNÃè~ÐxâÊ2'TÿÞÞÞÓëäî‡÷tåîà[Ù½ÙqÖ™ß,åï–éîç`ß™ÜiÝ!ãÔéÃñ˜õ’÷Äønú:ÿbN
—²„z!ü'12Þ8Ê?2=e@ò4Šÿ­ägÛGþ^"ã)Q–ö­ä}é2î¸ð4òGêÍêÍæ#âíÜÑÜè   îéê£ç&áãàÅãsæ0éÍìªðõöõgùmûSý–ì  ÔÔêf$   -5Ü?á>m5˜(ž,K
øEì/ù¬(CÌîççê”êÞñ×ïcìwé%æAäCã~ãÓèÊæ:æÛäàÆßJä;éïuñ|òTôƒöAú?ü; €Syè˜ '”/ï7uC`Ež3“
ëŸ ÀùÓþC
+/æ±ðAæœå‰íó½òòìsêßêíêkçòã¥ä'ç¸æLçRßUÚºà‰èòˆó¿ñXóƒõ¸øÂúkú²wÌ?ÃZ#/,5ÐAPIl7¡•[Ñàÿp$
óùTëôê ð'ôhð
ìkéÀï]ð4êZä©ä2è.çpÝG×dØÕãì¤ï¬ïWó/øËú‰ù´ûŠí
oò#¡*#3ø@OK]:uB
BžP Ð^Q4ýùòðŠô¹ö­ð¸ëêoïÍñìéæééªà¯×VÒFÝ•ç¹î{ï·ï•ô}ø¬úˆú&ÿÀÔ° }%Ì-z3ÊBŽCv)=mîïû3È »³OüöøÀùtõÔð›í·íÅðî‘êÈç·éºçùÜÖÇÖÞÝ‚æè¿é®ìÿñSöv÷²úå«g
p'®-U0ê:÷8^)Õré*Ð   È;
<
¦û†ø™øFøMõÝðï^ïfïígéæÝæºåàÝ•×@Ù\Þå7èòé½íó÷Où)ý¬î
€#r)|/â8˜8++øuL¬Ø{  Ý›
œ   æºûŠù!ú=ø½ôTðÖðòò#îênçîç´ã²ÜÙÚ{ß¸ã‘ææéEî’òÿõbùþHG   ;Ë o(s/\7)3¡(š½º¬i0ÿnå#Àý'üëù¬öHó!ñÇñƒñ5ïÝë¾èµçjåóßEÚÞØ«ÚqÞ¾á‘å*êµîAón÷5üÀ I+h#ž+K4K6Ò/Ù'Ê êQ{2¨¯Ýþ\üOúFöžòúïïï&ð>îfë-éræäá ÞcÛ­ÚµÛæÝ>á‹å1ê†î|ó"ù&þŸ»7ö#Á,·4Ü5Ó0ª)¦#)WÐk~€Vý_úÁöIó‹ðï¤î‘íeë
èóãîàúÞGÝ¨Û÷ÚèÛ1Þhá)åˆéïî·ôÞùËý4"@,¾8#ï,_6ï8X5//Ò(á#*m2þø*ýóùÌõäñ+ï(í¯ì:ëŸé³çäUá»ß1ÞöÜìÛ$Ü7Ý¼ß ãHç™ìlòü÷‹ü /g   •­`~'²0ý7^8A5‚/Ž)À#5o7v [Šþ-úÆöªòbïDíì ëlé_çã%á¿ß¦ÞÀÝ°ÜhÜ„ÜâÝ…àväÒéÈï¾õ!ûvÿxÄúV«:#O,œ5>:9.5ð.±( "„þ v}ÿÅú$÷9ó¡ïàì
ëÏéè/æ´âŠàCß±ÞTÞÈÝ4ÝüÜyÝBß‹â3çäìÑò5øïü,\
iÚh$&i/¿7o;\:55ÿ.<(!¦…äù    <hýøõ*ñî±ë1êéDç¦äâ_áßàŒà àŽßÛÞ´ÞPß6áÿãÄç7ìñÕõúlþ¥É=F`\.%Ž,Ã4W::|5´/D)‡":$Nh
DýTørô.ñ›íDë˜éýçJæ%ä]â~á”áÎáá”à€ß›Þ–Þ+à-ãlçcì‚ñ‰öûú)ÿ#æŸ|€ ù(c1X9<ò8u3æ,Ñ%
’v
!¥#‰%T)š1Q ŠõUú1
úÁmøü®üwú•ô óÒôå÷ÿúZöôíðò’õîò£ó.õ
øòùv÷ö‹øúü¤òDòèöâù÷ñgðjõ9ó`òTï5ôþß ÿ™CÎ„W
 e"B'”/, eKøÜþðæŸè\ ½þ÷úõ]ðSóSøúìøôóoòXóó‘ó“óÇôøöøÍøø~øúø1÷ˆöýö'øCøßó3ñåñÏóõôó‚óözûúþ þï2õ/t K"—$+q,æ‡“øàû  žŒ©
 6û$õìðÆñŽõòøçù[÷,ó>òÍñqò”ó+õ ÷ùòù-úÔøûö1ø˜úÓû)û“ø¨õ7óZóTôÁô1ôô’ôöö­ú¯ý•þý¡
íDk€ °#ø'Ë'• öý ;³  9R aüÝø¢õÝóbóÒôö‰öhõKôæóúôîõ´ö±öe÷'ø
úéûYýoüü=üÙüŽü³ú¶÷ÜõòõÀöûöùõØôÄôöaø£ú!üQþØ ~‘   k «ÞrÞ„Á®¡H}¥   UÉþ—ýÎûIúÇ÷Ãõâôëôþô¢ôäó óôºôªõ1öÉö©÷ƒø=ùú¤ú{ûgûHúíøø€÷|÷'÷~öÙõ_õpõ+ö?÷³ølúGüÈþè¤ã   —ÖÂ³!Ó g@ÆÉ|r   ƒ‡ Eþ|ü‹úË÷Bõ°ó¬ó¢óóòñ ññð_ñuòFó(ôÃôö@÷ôøMù«ùÂùÛùÝù/ú¦ù(ùnøI÷£ööÁõö°öª÷WùûtýG ;‰o
FmÓÈ    !!}M3y4¶ ¦ÎŒÿyü0ù[ö®óNòŸñ2ñðï?îhî`ï¹ð~ñ`òdó ô!ö«÷øÀø
ù„ùÎùèù!ùø¢÷òöŸöYö—ö'÷øùJûEý8 ¥J
ä
”ºœð!§ ÉÃ¸ØÊ
˜=, Ðü­øÉôòøð¿ðBðgï4î–íÍííîòïýð\ñò¦ò"ô«õøö@÷´÷•øù>ù>ùùÄø¤ø3øì÷%ø‘øÿøòùSû¬ü¢þ»Ä7
®
„]F·!M!, J … dã¾fL
¡ =üøjôÇñqð
ðï9îZí´ìíþíïåïªðqñ±òôäô¼õbö>÷-ø±øäøîøÜø©økøøþ÷=ø£ø,ù!ú”ûýøþ_È‰Î &
×ÎÖ-F!#"!± ÿ f §O”Š®ÿ0ý¶ø…ô‡ñðïuï&ï6îÚììTìvíÙîÞïWð+ñòÓóŽôõGöÛöµ÷‚ø×øäøõøøøìøðøØøÖøùvùúúú?ü¡ý=ÿdž    8×{0Ãþ!F!!þ 9 Úx»
2ÔòýUùõXò]ð•ïýî0î!í>ìOìøì$î`ïðûð#òOóKôdõ9ö¦ö„÷†øÿø'ù6ùMù_ù\ù-ùùKù›ùóùú©û*ý¤þK ]Åœ©
æ
qC=áb!î!C"L#®"„ øû
íeÿRùsõ8óñ/ï|íQì1ìóë¾ëóëµìRîÚïŒðAñMòºóõ€õýõ%÷tøYùYùCùÃùcú£ú_ú,ú®úAûUûMûžûÅü=þPÿŽ w¢2Â   av!õçÀ¼ \!‹"§"˜ ·]Ÿ
Ô   ûÔöôÚñÔï7îCíÏìì?ì]ìí:î¤ï¨ð?ñ"ò^ókôõ›õ}öÒ÷Æøù.ùù9úªúžúúñúwûºû¶ûûûÞüþ+ÿK äö$}Û
¢ÿíê !"à RêÉÒ^
âèýÌørõÚòŸð¸îÈíåìÍìì¹ì™ê2ë¿ðxóÀó›òÐñ¾ñõí÷—ùù¿÷çö|øûÝü!üGúKùiú¾üfþ”ýü¸ûý1ÿ· ª À GÌ^c L
ÕÎ!˜†¤ÉX¨ÖŠ#?®  ÷IþOùjõó¥ðšî®íùì¬ìÄìÝìííî6ðñèòñóâôÛõÝö”÷UøFùú´úMûöûü%üýóüýüíýKþIþ„þDÿ,ÿïþ( c ¾ ¿L¬½ý’   J`
ýIØB¦Ö(£ìAáôÎi‚ÿ’û÷õ¿ò²ð„ïÒî¦î×îõîïeðñÖò?ôOõ^ö/÷ý÷Òø¯ùŠúdû!üàü^ýÌý=þ¨þÿ‡ÿðÿ~ ã 7ŒÍO‡óAæ4€à‹jí­>á+   ž   P
ƒ
½
ó
{

k   \­½ßÿ¹ý¢ûù·÷öÓôäó|ógóÕó\ô1õ0ö‡÷éøKúûÎü½ý®þTÿ € qö}òcÍ&¢ëêÂQâ:YÈ2{ îÿ›ÿÿÜþfþËýlýýÆüüTü0ü.üEüaüÉüHýôý¤þvÿL 3
òÂŒKî€¸ø!VêpÏ<BÚ€ÿ+þÏüûuú‹ùÂøcø?ø•øùøhùåùNúÀú(û‰ûü¬üšýÇþ XŽÁ\)Ã5    _   ÕÌ}ï~¦4  ÿ—ý^üÀûOûûú¹úú7ú2úúüùéùõùGúøúßûôüþ;ÿ_ ‚ÀÛâˆ8?~Ê<ÀlÚ–Œ¹
fGAÿEþ$þþÖý|ýöü¬ü‡üqü–üÇü¸ü†ü™üæüTý‘ýËýþoþèþaÿ¢ÿ~ÿÿ þ5þþþIþ›þÿzÿûÿ‚ "Û aá!õ<t#ížye58lÄ|Yîù‹%Å # cÿˆþ×ýýœü1ü¹ûCû!ûXûäû‰üAýþÜþÿv #Â
ëß›Qå } þÿ“ÿ^ÿgÿbÿ«ÿðÿ* C j i q H C + þÿÊÿ¾ÿ¿ÿæÿ c « ô ¾ Ä Ä É ® ™ S ! ÑÿŒÿ>ÿÿ¿þþEþXþnþ±þÍþ5ÿqÿÝÿ& § Ð ù %ú )ç ú · Ð o e   ¢ÿ·ÿ`ÿyÿ8ÿ_ÿ<ÿoÿgÿ|ÿ¨ÿàþLþaÿ¹ÿ  ¼ÿ \ÿØÿdÿÎÿnÿ `ÿ¦ÿSÿõÿÉÿ0  f C è    í ˜ Å Mï .¾ Ä k ‹   E éÿ ÏÿÕÿ‘ÿ¯ÿzÿ™ÿtÿ„ÿ…ÿ™ÿaÿwÿdÿ¢ÿ¿ÿÅÿôÿòÿ< ( :  U * D   E * € 7 U p n  ; k ÿÿ¸ þoÿÕïç÷e$õ—oïÏ-ü9ÿž
ý¤ù«yýªÿÿºÿhÿh´ý€þeÿ‡  þê + H( !ÿ—ðþ¬ ü’ü   ú8ùNü(± Z1ñý…9´n þIþßóÉõÎûJôÿî>%mþa/ÿƒð . Xÿëþ½PüFäþN,þž.ú?¤øaD÷Eêû<µþ?þÉ 6üÇøÅ*øµÿùÝþ«û³ÿ¥ÿ{¢ýÿezýjöýt¸úsÐÿ ŒûŸrû9ŸøEÍûœãû~ÿÜþ÷ÿ6£þQ ý ÿ¹þbÏþ{ýs.þžþ& óþ¬%ÿõÿÿIp :– \þ•• µÿßýºÿŸþ¯þÆÿ:þ  ÿ^þÓÿ¾ý±ÿ×cþì4þ`ÿÃ dÿî7ý(Ÿ {þ½ Íþ×ÿÐÿ, œÿSýÒô™òáùñùlGG
Ñ
N;C‡–¯ýJû|ùuùÏúmù6üiû   ù³–LÐD  «Ä^ýIþ:ú›úžüºýóþþ]_üÏþ¿ÿ±Ÿúºÿ©BþÿfÆ& -}ÿ2þÈÿ’ýŸ <Öþöÿv¦‡”â“ (ãþ:ÿÞ› 5 >L LI ûWNøúüçGþàýdÿ£ýòðIûHýÊø¹ÿß ³¤T ÂË|þ§û ñúbøhüDºRþ0Ì  ý­þš    DÿŒ«úh Ý ÿ“ÿŠ.Á ë ÿü·AýúøR ­»:ÿB þòøÎúoýA}eûEÿîÿûQûJýâ— þ¿í¡ü¥úÇýºþzùãi xþbý þúÌû¥ˆÿ%úëþ× üœþlúÌýBýÿÈÿ¨ŠäS Gþ‰ÑýËöFøŠ…øBþxŒ…kpø™ ,ûƒü×þ{ Ò ´ý% ó1{ ½ÿ;þ–ýèýÙüRüXÿrŠÇ.ÿŒýÉü ¬ÿŠÿîÊþ÷ûúâþ“ç}ïöÂþ¾ø
ø
þ+ \æù· B,ÿäüÎûˆ²ÿÕø¹ü¤ÂÔÿü–î˜ÿXÿóü9û,ËÂŠÿaü-üíûàøöþ¬ašþ¿øŸûB‡ÿœþoû  [ûÿ_·|ðük¢šþ‘ý<Äzèÿ-9
m™ÿÙÿÌ,ùãùXÁƒÄöøÉüjý!ú§÷7üVýãúeô¶òxõøúßûÕûÝüðý~üµû€ÿXšßãÜgLQ¾½u
Ñ¶DÇŠÎiA>ü¢û6ÿýšô¢÷úù„ùÿðÛìòë‚ðu÷Ðú³ï?è)éàî‚ï–òØòø3ýÝüâõÉø¾ü=.ˆ·
œ
P
¿Ê—Ð¿ßÊj«@ž1#ŸÜí !û5ú•ñ´îºíGîEæóá^ã
æSçýã¥Þ_ßEãçiè®ê´ïÑôèõUõö®ùÑþ„RGb   8æ¾Ä·»ë!,z ÚS"u!"I…
(b
oûåÿÅó¾üîó÷¥í?èGÞzÝÌááæÌåKá!ÝÎÝàâCæ¾êXð·òÊòÿñ˜ó(ùIþÿ’ãÎ m_« p ø" %*³)†*#­›¨
™ËÏýù,ù»ùø;ð9é×ë4é­ë8ÝhÝ°Ü„á!ä#àXßãà(äOæØå2èâí¦ó+ùÅüÒýÑÿÅ´»ÊáU\ù Ü#¡-è1:.·  \>¤Ù‡
6þ?ú.F9 àõ
î˜éë    îbëcæãaß»Þ‡à¸âšä!ã(âíàä%êÓï§ñiñ©òFö§üÒîj#Õ¹Ÿp)¡. .ù.4n%ÙW-¤ZÏô
  D (è÷õî/ïìÏê™èÞæKædäàªÞYÜÞàáìäDèÅèê£ëKîùòc÷ùúDþ°øÄTÈê–(S25?t@ (

âé„ù$z> }ÿ½ýkø/ó|ðïTïqëéçˆæãtäKààÑÞ×à’âçå•êî(î?ëê¡í1õ•ýT˜ÄÉÍ¸¢ <(54<=œD$6Øj 3ÐÝŸñ4ÿK:åøøvïWòð"ïâí<ê”ææUá‘ß à‚ÞñâÐäŽèÁé+ê©ë·ìOíøî­ñöûü³  K
(ØÅÃ&¾41<C×1Èî
•€ý
xÿ<Žöþù\ö©ð÷Ùöäòˆëdç$èKê’é)ç3ÞyÜøàÏæñìêêüè@ëBíÖì€í›ðÄ÷òþ&Ëˆ$â«ÏT!a%è0ä?éFâ(Ý/þ= 2|$<Æa¹ 4öPô3ò°øÛò£ïÔè8è;ééévåDâÒÞ¸âè–íîÆìëŸêkëÍì«ï3ôYù ý ³Sø
H‰ï' 8(W5>@I@‹%¨&XÑDVâ±¬åÁÿ‚ö.ô’ñdö?óïðëþçJçFèîèèæ  å;â0äé´írï”ë@êÊêDí0ïNï;ñõõ1üi pó÷Žƒ@Ö–#¬+ 9ñ=r7¸£è¢>éÞzö»þ÷°ô:õÊõèômðPìñéÎèŽéOè-æ\æ¦æjèÙèÎê¸íÿïªíë¨ëFîñöðÖñ†ô†ùðþÖMî    Î
9£«#Ž(Ä,^8¯@[/Â‚”/ #f(‘wü«ùQø…ùÑ÷ôô$ïFìfì¶ì5ê>èçféæ²ä÷âtèöîÛòµðºé’çîépí•ïéño÷lýT 2 l åð
bu&ð.~@ºCá./3       ËÞ{°    ,ù¸÷ÒúÖûv÷`ñàêÓíQîŒî£êŽévê/ëIêýåOâdè[î[óÓð‰ë<ê´ë]îßî ïlõaý˜ 8þ†û” # xR± ®-ö8Bj8Çè   Š-M÷Aùúþhý~÷•ñ  ñ˜òÔðVìJè–é»îßïPì±çüæséÊìò#ð]ïWíjìÓì&í×î[ñôSøÌûüVüÜýÅ
–;æÁ/‘8qEP6kÇ
    /YÁ
þ›e¶ö¶ù6úèüÂõïðñ¦ñ8ð®ì¦æbëíæí~ìÍê*í¸í¾îð‹óõèòŽï¬ëècë”ñEö¿ùAüsý=û6÷~øýÿ= °$uŸ#è.8©@Œ7«¼ôý•
Èµâå}øëûÕùSôŽòQòýôÏð‡ë"íºé‚ê?ë#ìŸñHñHñAðõï¤ôa÷{öØô  óZó2ï˜è/ê­ñdø-úêö”ö…ørø•ù¥ûguî›—ï'±6ý?B½1¼/ç©O"?ÈÚUú!÷!ýôú]ïËíÎðSöäï|çöçœìsí2ííhóWõð¶î¹ðxø’ý#ùõÎôòÞëCæ'ê¹óÒ÷R÷ ÷Jø¥ùƒö!õeúÀTS²'Ð/~5?[H_-œ4BÎ
_ÂMÖ;Iõ9ñyúô4îÐìBôöÉì¯æáê³ì©ívì[ïZ÷Ï÷þô—ô”öOúOú‚ö0ôÖòžîèéFèÔìhó©õ#ö©÷.ùÐøËõ¾õû¬ ‡Æ
Íll&~,5;?C/2ûX>ŽÔ¥9
9
Ó^ù'óÐúaõ^ëmí]ògóí%æìì½î ìùì0ïö÷Úøèõ­óaò¾öpù•÷ö×õËóÀíHæaèNðfõ…ø˜ùNûkûgõÚñC÷~þÎž¬˜u"–'±,ž5Ö@>ê)¡Ã(V¡
¶Jþ(ùãø÷»ïÊì|ðòï…îêNì)ðîíð‘ô´ø÷1÷[ù¼ù÷†ô±ôñô=òÐïßëúèÃìGñÃòzôk÷Kû›úcö÷êúWÿáç^0Ü"(T1:>AA<Ó&VŒüÜÍüÆ
l6ÿÄøá÷`ô¯ìõë‘ï©ðUð»ìíƒï‡ízî®ð–ô1ø)ùãúeýuý+ü_ö9ñYññ“î6íì`í‚ñÖò$óºõñ÷Xùê÷÷Óúý@
4Uè&Í1Ä7=´;ø)~€™¹t Tu   àN Jü|÷böbð:ìýïœñ§ñíbë.îÆîbï¯ðÈôLùŽû¸úcýŠþ2þ>÷˜óÉôcñûñ#ðpñðNïáï„ï§ñõ‘öøpø”ø û™úgþ®¹™",n4Þ7á8¬9)
¶F#Õþž ­e«þüTø}õÏîYëúíð\ï“ísîAñJðÐïºówö¤ùSû[ýhÿŸ Š ¸ýâù«õôñêï™î/îÍî…ïƒð…ñÝñùòPóÇôö ÷·øÞúpý{OxÖ¾ú&d,•5±7·:œ4¾$9û
ÿØýEý
 ’‡:µúçóõòÐìøêÎì¼î•ñ;ïƒïòÍñkôLö)øðû_ü°þ= Ûÿ ù¥÷<õÖð•ðð¹ñ)óóçñžð€ðñòòócõÞö   ûdû*û<ÿñ
B¯>!¾+ƒ5ô55ó9v.tLöMüŒü=ýß ¶ÿñþêüæõ„óºîê¼êîOï^ï(ðÂóNõGóYöoø¤û>þÿHÿ
\ {û*÷Ëó“ïzîzíRîzòXñVïBð»òwôðHð'ö¯ùûHýdåÀíÉ 0,ö2·2)85=U0Ã!¸h3þƒùŽù€þ‡ XþÙö:ó#î2ë±ìâìˆï4ñvòô„óâòŽö}÷Mù_üå _’˜áøyñZñ8îð£ñØñèó\ôðñÄìïPô½ó¡ñmõoú/ü&û|þ¡ñ(%j/È4á5•7Ñ5§+ ØåûÎøžùÛûiýiÿKý5útõ4ñtï
îîCðªïyñúòõòýôÂô­÷‰ûUü$ÿï ŸÅÕ ¶þKý‹ù“öGð/ì›ï—îiî#ï;ï(ô¼ò°ð^òãóì÷Xù»øþ%í è$ø#)µ.£1á6~4;+Cÿ!ø•óé÷ŸøòøœúË÷Š÷¹ô0ñÓóŒó¨õúöZõ–ö‹õ¡ôôôô?ùÞüòýB 6²ÿŽü±õò¶ñ6í_íïaðÿïDîHðfó]ó¤ô}ö(ú»ýšý£þßvOU“%¦(ˆ*S+µ/2Ù).!¬Hÿ÷ðïyðYð2ñÕõröTøáùø7ú„úù²ù"÷ïöÿõuóô_ôŸ÷ëû¢ý /MŠÉ kþüoùåõ!ðžìOíOì¨ëìLï´ó-õmõ ÷*úþ®þûý¸   w'
µ>Š#z'Ñ%
',*„,­(ç ªFø¦ðdì™ëôë½ìËñ)õðøû»ü¾ l«ÿÿ–üú×öô2óðóöIùlü/ÿ‡5ô¹ÿâû¯÷Ãó“ïUìÆéFêmëõìGðóÀö#úSü8 Çãæ3    Šá#wÒ Ò"ø!%V%<'%${¶ò÷Wðâêç˜ä„è‡í“ñBöXúpvÛ4k8ú¢õµòÒòhóðò”ôÂø‡ûgþfÿ• Ú ;þúö“ñƒî×êéÜéšëáíüðîôŸú²ÿ°
|
Ú‹³ú9H—!¦!Ý!2!Ûß    -úøôYíüæOçÝèêéÿì|îQ÷þ‰ ô    Ê   PL 0ýóùc÷‹òsñ+óÄó   õÄõ§ø.üü•ûôùÛøÝøöóò)ñjñÍò³ò‹ó²÷güwæ^
p¶
Om,ëèö-kVQZ˜    @ò ñüÆö‰òHð°îEí­ë0íyñ/õJøŒû5ÿ‹™ Þ#† ›þ7üû!ú©ùjøø#ùôùºú´ú;ûoü!ý:ýýýþòýQýÔü”üý%ýÑüóü]ýBþ'ÿõÿ`ñ¶2©9    S
ŽæÑ
õŒ7
Mª

    eŒÜâaÿ&ý/ûMúyù­øJøøÁ÷–÷÷ðöÜö÷‰÷·÷ øŠødùrú]û3ü8ý^þzÿY I0ÏkØ  
ÿâýÜüõûKû½úzú‰ú
û„ûLühý¶þ- ·JåŒ –   T\
í
F©Ê‚®
:˜
YËM õýçûûùYø÷îõõQôÏóó£óô»ôŽõºöö÷Vù´úüaý»þúÿõº=¨å¹nt»ý 2 „ÿàþ<þ¤ý&ýåüÅüÍüèü/ý™ý'þ´þ?ÿ  Æ àºÃÝ 04 Ù   [
Ž
‰
}

q   ,šëÿÿ0ý«û_úùø,÷·ö@ööôõ7ö¸öy÷Cøùú9ûOü]ýGþEÿ  ó ¤sÄêöêÏ¡z)Ø{-Ý “ a F + : J p ¦ ç _´s¹ñ.UX<ç¹l&»g˜  ÿÿ¦þþŸý3ýáüü2ü÷ûÐû­û«û–û–û¬ûÜûü+ü}üÓü>ý¥ýþ…þÿŽÿ" — 5£9¥]Áô7Eqj|Â¹—M¹rœ+Ë N  ‚ÿEÿçþ¤þPþ2þÒýÂý¦ýÊýˆý¿ýsýÂý{ýüý²ýþý¯ý1þþxþ8þšþÄþ)ÿÿlÿ~ÿ øÿe A     « gš sÑ ÛB%óì÷YüñÑ~aÚ›OH    su]fÿ×ÿÓ i»ú)ý1þø ý¢ M! wÁ îþõøÆûéû3ÿ¾üÚÿUˆþÔ9 óÿêþ nö„÷
ÿ ¯ 3Aü ôKúÞúXüàúŠ›þ…ð< 6 ¿“?ý`üÿIÄþ&üqrÀ­ý­ÒühÿlñúÞü   Ú»ü1ýb´CþxÿBÿ\ÿÿ´û
pþºüüÚþ8 Kþrý˜ÿMŽÿ«ÿfÿ’5ÿ]ÿâþo "ÿÓÿŽ› Ê %lZ ¼Àÿç ¯ s  ¾ÿb  ·þA 2ÿF (ÿÿ€ÿq ÿ8 Š™ÿ 8 ¿ k §þ»þè §Ôþµþûÿpÿbü¹þ<óüªü³˜Aýžý¿E´ý:ü9ÿt iü¸þ2¿ þaÿÉ   íÿ‘Ýl ®ÿBÿ’KþLþìàÿÈýE Òþ­þÙþ­Ò=ÿþÊÌàÿpý‡ ÊzþAûÿC"ÿ<ügÿÐŒ.ýsÿ•‡,þ+þm¶!ÿ1ý¶þ'ûëüCþ›Ó÷þÜü|EŠ Wý7ÿAÒŠüNü™ —>þóýîGb Ñý{ ¡Ñ ðýõþ¤ ‹ÿ0ý­þmÿ. ¥ ‡9  T 4 ìÿ<  ¦ ¥þ×ýyÿ¥ Y Žþ ÿÝ¬Ùþ–ý ¢} Êý °Q¼þÛÿ/ØþËþR ÛþÏÿ¬ 
 Uÿˆÿ#  µÿ»ÿ  þÿêÿ                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
----Nuance_NMSP_vutc5w1XobDdefsYG3wq
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Audio"; paramName="TEXT_TO_READ"
Content-Type: audio/x-wav;codec=pcm;bit=16;rate=8000
Nuance-Context: 101f04eb-2393-45e1-a005-528b11748a7f


----Nuance_NMSP_vutc5w1XobDdefsYG3wq
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="QueryResult"
Content-Type: application/JSON; charset=utf-8
Nuance-Context: 101f04eb-2393-45e1-a005-528b11748a7f

{"TTSStatus":"Success","result_type":"NVC_TTS_CMD","NMAS_PRFX_SESSION_ID":"04d4d3f8-309b-441a-bce3-098a06d7238d","NMAS_PRFX_TRANSACTION_ID":"1"}
----Nuance_NMSP_vutc5w1XobDdefsYG3wq--
```

Comment: sorry !! i made the changes

Comment: Are you sure, that your code enters `if` or `ifelse` section? You could add some `print "entered if"` after `if content_type == "audio/x-wav" and len(payload):` and `elif content_type == "application/json":`. Then you should see some output in the console. Otherwise the `content_type` is not detected correctly.

Comment: it is not generating the line.pcm and line.txt.

Comment: You are not constructing a valid multipart/mixed message. multipart/mixed is a *container for other mime messages*, but your text file contains no such messages.

Comment: it works for one input, example - I am hungry, later i will get a response which as mime. I will add my response also